# how to display text and image in GridView

Tags: android, layout

here is [my string](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=90D26B3C24DAF89C%21134) which I must work with which is stored in an array called txt

the text and link shows up fine in the gridView cell:
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
 label.setText(Html.fromHtml(txt[position]));
```

but the problem is, how can i get that [image](https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8596/15724883678_49bd3829d2_m.jpg) to show ? Here is my xml file located in the menu folder which will fill each individual cell of the gridView:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
</ImageView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/grid_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="9sp" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [AQuery](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) for downloading images from the internet, here is an example of how i do it:

```
public static void loadImageFromUrl(ImageView imageView, String url) {
    AQuery aq = new AQuery(imageView);
    Bitmap bitmap = aq.getCachedImage(url);
    if (bitmap == null) {
            aq.image(url, memCache, fileCache); //memCache and fileCache are booleans.
    } else {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

And in your gridview you call:

```
 loadImageFromUrl(R.id.grid_image, theUrlOfImage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should dowload image from URL and then display it in ImageView. Here is the sample code: [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Or you can use library for downloading and displaying images: https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).
Code is short and simple and it can handle cache, memory and thread.

If you declare an 'imageView' in the same way you have declared 'label', it's just one row:

```
Picasso
   .with(context)
   .load(url)
   .into(imageView);
```